# How to change|edit the device path on a docker volume?

Tags: docker

At some point I created this volume

`docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt device=/media/mario/Files/mysql-data --opt o=bind mysql-data`

For some reason the path `/media/mario/Files/mysql-data` changed to `/media/mario/Files1/mysql-data` now when trying to start a container

`docker start mysql-server-main`

I get this message

```
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql-data/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /media/mario/Files/mysql-data:/var/lib/docker /volumes/mysql-data/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
Error: failed to start containers: mysql-server-main
```

When inspecting the volume

`docker volume inspect mysql-data`

I get this information

```
[
     {
         "CreatedAt": "2023-05-10T21:41:06-06:00",
         "Driver": "local",
         "Labels": null,
         "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql-data/_data",
         "Name": "mysql-data",
         "Options": {
             "device": "/media/mario/Files/mysql-data",
             "o": "bind",
             "type": "none"
         },
         "Scope": "local"
     }
]
```

Can I change "device": "/media/mario/Files/mysql-data" to "device": "/media/mario/Files1/mysql-data"?

Is it the best way to resolve this scenario?

Comment: Can you delete and recreate the volume with the different path?  Can you use the direct Docker bind-mount syntax, without creating the intermediate named volume?

Comment: if you dont care about the previously created volume , the simplest way is to delete the volume and recreate the volume 

by doing this 

~~ docker volume rm mysql-data ~~

and 

 ~~ docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt device=/media/mario/Files1/mysql-data --opt o=bind mysql-data ~~

just as David maze suggested 
but if you want to retain the file  you might need to back up the data first 

and  then 

docker volume rm mysql-data
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt device=/media/mario/Files1/mysql-data --opt o=bind mysql-data

Comment: The problem is that this volume contains a set of database that I need. Could I copy the contents of the volume to a new location where I point a new volume?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by making a small adjustment to the mounting unit. Got superuser support and now it works as expected. I share the link to the question and collaboration that helped me solve the problem https://superuser.com/questions/1834976/what-is-the-correct-way-to-rename-a-mount-point